# Netbeans project documentation

Tags: netbeans, ant, documentation, project

**lazy dont have to read this**

I have to work on an old netbeans project which is kinda messy. The previous autor changed a lot in some .properties and .xml files and add ant scripts. (Aplication is designed for Websphere, and it have some requirements)

Unfortunatly today doesn't work. Some important values was stored in private.properties (I dont know what exacly was), ant script don't run, and few versions issue apper. So first I have to tidy this mess, but I dont know about netbeans project well. Unfortunatly I have problem to find documentation to all of it.

Netbeans project is based on ant project. Fortunatley ant have manual here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html . But (I assume that) 'nbproject' folder and its inner files are not part of ant project. I can't find documentation about it. Maybe I blind or something, but I didn't found it on NetBeans side. IMHO netbeans side is kinda messy as well.

**straight to the point**

I am searching for documentation for netbeans project, where will be written about files *project.xml*, *project.properties* etc. What they contain and even how to write them on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document explains freeform project configuration in detail. You should be able to find what you need in there. If I were in your position, I would create a new project that has all the frameworks like your original project and then look at the project metadata files of the new project for some direction. IMO this is far easier than trying to author the project.xml files from scratch.

http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/freeform-config.html